# Max value from one column when several columns needed

Tags: sql-server, max, where-clause, multiple-columns

I've been wrestling with this and haven´t been able to find the proper solution. I have a very simple sql Db with four columns,
(product) code,
concept (1 purchse, 2 return),
supplier (and),
date_of_purchase

I need to get:

| code  |  supplier  |    date_of_purchase |

I have tried:

```
SELECT  
    code,
    supplier,
    MAX (date_of_purchase)

FROM SSQL_E03.dbo.pchs

WHERE   concept =1
GROUP BY code, supplier
ORDER BY code
```

If I don't group by code AND supplier, I get an error, but of course I don´t need the last purchase from every supplier but ONLY the very last purchase for every code, I tried also

```
WHERE concept = 1 AND date_of_purchase = MAX(date_of_purchase)
```

which didn't work either

Could someone help me getting

code,
supplier,
and (ONLY THE VERY LAST) date_ of purchase

within a single row for every code?

Thanks ALOT

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using:

Comment: Might want to check the `HAVING` clause in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Most databases support the ANSI SQL `row_number()` function:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM (SELECT p.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY supplier ORDER BY date_of_purchase DESC) as seqnum
      FROM SSQL_E03.dbo.pchs p
      WHERE concept = 1
     ) p
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Gordon's answer is helpful. However, the result is to group by supplier other than code. So I made it as below to get the latest purchase for every code.

```
SELECT p.*
FROM (
SELECT p.*,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY code ORDER BY date_of_purchase DESC) as latest
FROM stackOver  p
WHERE concept = 1
) p
WHERE latest=1;
```